# Python, TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to compare two list of lists if they are equal.

```
if grafo.node[va,vb] == grafo.node[va,vb]:
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python33/Archive/PythonGrafos/Alpha.py", line 85, in <module>
menugrafos()
File "C:/Python33/Archive/PythonGrafos/Alpha.py", line 55, in menugrafos
Beta.criararesta(grafo,va,vb)
File "C:/Python33/Archive/PythonGrafos\Beta.py", line 29, in criararesta
if grafo.node[va,vb] == grafo.node[va,vb]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

I'm inserting integers in the lists.  What does this error mean?

Comment: The code you wrote above is different from the code in the traceback. And the error message is pretty clear.

Comment: You also appear to be comparing an element to itself. You have `grafo.node[va][vb]` on both sides of the comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error suggests that `va` and `vb` are strings, so you cannot use them as indexes. If they contain some integer you want to use for index, then use `[int(va)][int(vb)]` and it will probably work.

Also interjay is right your code is different than the traceback!

Answer (score 1):

What is in va and vb? It needs to be an int, assuming that node is a list. If you do want it to use a string, as an index, use a dict instead.
What you probably want to do is:

```
grafo.node[int(va)] == grafo.node[int(vb)]
```

Comment: I did that change and recived:
IndexError: list index out of range

I'm inserting integers in the lists.

Comment: What is the content of `grafo.node`, and what is the value of `vb` and `va`?

Comment: node is an empthy list. va is 0, vb is 1.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, you might want to use a different structure altogether, since you this isn't valid: `[][0]`. I can't tell what the exact solution would be until I can really see what the context is.

Comment: The context is, i want to insert a graph arc, and i want to test to see if that arc was already inserted in the list grafo.node. If it's inserted i want to send an error message.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you really want to do is this: `if len(grafo.node)>0: throw exception`